# Share Wi-Fi settings from iOS to external device with zero configuration mode

Tags: ios, arduino, wifi, settings, adhoc

I'm looking at Stackoverflow and all over the internet to be able to configure the Wi-Fi of an external device by sharing the Wi-Fi settings of the iPhone, in a zero configuration mode. This new device is an arduino device that I want to program.

I try to do the same thing that is done with Apple's HomeKit devices. When we want to configure a new HomeKit device to connect to our Wi-Fi, we must perform the following steps:

- Plug in the new device.
- Go to settings > wifi and select the new device. The iPhone finds it since the new device has surely created an ad-hoc network. but on the iPhone it does not appear as a normal wifi connection, but as a new device.
- We click on the new device and a wizard opens in which we will select the wifi to which we want to connect the new device.
- iPhone connects to the network as hoc of the device.
- iPhone shares the password of the network.
  -The device is configured with the new wifi and restarted. After the restart, it will connect to the newly configured wifi.
- iPhone reconnects to the Wi-Fi network and I look for the new device and if it finds it, it will finish the configuration satisfactorily.

All this is surely a standard protocol and I am looking for how to configure the arduino so that I can create that special ad hoc network (something with bonjour?) and be able to receive the configuration from the iPhone (some standard function?).

Does anyone know how to configure my new device so that iOS recognizes it as a new device to configure?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are describing Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC).  To use this technology you must join the Apple MFi program and implement specific hardware in your embedded device.

Some more information is available in [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1942/_index.html)

> - Accessory configuration — If you want to configure an accessory to join the user’s local network (for example, you’re creating a companion app for a set of wireless speakers and the goal is to get those speakers on to the user’s home network), you have two options:
>
>   - Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC) — To learn more about WAC, watch [WWDC 2013 Session 700 Designing Accessories for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/700/), which introduced the technology, and [WWDC 2014 Session 701 Designing Accessories for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/701/), which describes enhancements made in iOS 8 that let you configure a WAC accessory from within your app.
>   - HomeKit — You can ask the system to scan for, pair and configure any unpaired HomeKit accessories by calling the `addAndSetupAccessories(completionHandler:)` method on `HMHome`. To learn more about this, watch [WWDC 2016 Session 710 What’s New in HomeKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/710/).
>
> **Important: Both WAC and HomeKit accessories must be built under the aegis of the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)**.

Comment: Damn apple. This would have been so useful as an open standard